# How to create a total quantity based upon multiple criteria from 2 arrays

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, sum, vlookup, google-query-language

What I'm trying to accomplish is going to be illustrated from the below picture, the example spreadsheet is linked as well.

I need to create function that will sum `Quantity Columns G & D` where `ID Columns B & E` is less than 5000. Then display those results to the corresponding `ID in Column J`.
Lastly, the quantities for the `Materials` in the `Chain Material` section need to carry over to the respective `ID in Column H`.

I do NOT need to sum anything from `Column D` where the `ID` from `Column B` is greater than 5000, that information is useless.

Expected result can be seen next to each cell in Column K.

Thank you in advance!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1seoOaGytQ8wKH-wXR7hhN1YGdWiNNNhMIyIpCzRAMG4/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use in J4:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(H4:H, QUERY({B4:D; E4:G}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col3) group by Col1"), 2, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Works fantastic! I did change the first array to `=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(H4:H, QUERY({FILTER(B4:D, B4:B < 5000); E4:G}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col3) group by Col1"), 2, 0)))` to account for any possibility of ID crossover.